# Google Spreadsheets importxml aspx

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-sheets

Dears, my question is as follow:
please see my table
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-oyXZHjmt69FpZI2d8NEAPh5ZAAlVljTNdeypUd38g/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to download list of exhibitors by `import xml`
And I even can download first page of it. (you could see in table).

But the matter is I can't understand how to download other pages, because table made by Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets import functions only can import content that is available without user interaction on the source. You should check if the source allow the use of URL parameters. If so, you should make a formula for each table page.

Comment: Thank you!
Unfortunately, this site don't allow to use URL parametrs.
so how I could take this information? I mean I understand that use different way, but which?